# "The image #1 could not be loaded" error in html/css code

Tags: html, css, portfolio

I'm creating a portfolio and have been trying to get this portfolio-box to open links to some of my work on my google drive. Whenever you click on the picture it pops up with an error that says "1 of 10 The image #1 could not be loaded". The link can then be clicked on at "The image #1" and it redirects to my files on my goggle drive. 
The link to my portfolio is: https://tdblanton3.github.io/portfolio.travis/

Here is the code I have:

```
<!-- Portfolio Section -->
  <section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
          <a class="portfolio-box" href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iIMsUtdX1lVSAiQNdXvnZq9RAnp4hiog?usp=sharing">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
              <div class="project-category text-white-50">
                Cardiovascular Disease Analysis
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Analysis of Cardiovascular Disease Dataset Using Python
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
          <a class="portfolio-box" href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cH3s3MfmYcWkf-5PuQQyEVf4wagjj5Z5?usp=sharing">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/2.jpeg" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
              <div class="project-category text-white-50">
                Housepricing Analysis
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Statistical Analysis of Housing Prices Using Excel
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
          <a class="portfolio-box" href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iXTYgfr11IQugQ1Q4O8KE3nXKGx2N1y3?usp=sharing">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/3.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
              <div class="project-category text-white-50">
                Lariat Fleet Analysis
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Predictive Analytics Using Excel
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
          <a class="portfolio-box" href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iIMsUtdX1lVSAiQNdXvnZq9RAnp4hiog?usp=sharing">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/4.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
              <div class="project-category text-white-50">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
          <a class="portfolio-box" href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iIMsUtdX1lVSAiQNdXvnZq9RAnp4hiog?usp=sharing">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/5.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
              <div class="project-category text-white-50">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
          <a class="portfolio-box" href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iIMsUtdX1lVSAiQNdXvnZq9RAnp4hiog?usp=sharing">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/6.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption p-3">
              <div class="project-category text-white-50">
                Category
              </div>
              <div class="project-name">
                Project Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I think I'm missing a key piece of code here that is causing the error. Any suggestions?!

Answer (score 0):

just try on one of them, instead of

```
<a class="portfolio-box" href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cH3s3MfmYcWkf-5PuQQyEVf4wagjj5Z5?usp=sharing">
```

use

```
<a class="portfolio-box" href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iIMsUtdX1lVSAiQNdXvnZq9RAnp4hiog">
```

and see if that works